# How can I safely remove a CRUD module built with yo (mean.js)

Tags: crud, mean-stack, meanjs

How can I safely remove a CRUD module built with `yo meanjs:crud-module <module-name>` ?

Is it enough just to delete folder and server files?

Comment: I don't get why all that people find this question "unclear". Can it be more clear than this?

Comment: Yes. Adding a list of the folders would be helpful to users. Here are the folders I deleted when I removed the Articles collection:
/public/modules/articles , 
/app/controllers/articles.server.controller.js ,
/app/models/articles.server.model.js ,
/app/routes/articles.server.routes.js ,
/app/tests/articles.server.model.test.js

Comment: @lupus because SO has become a hive for question nazis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is all there is to it. The meanjs system is designed to utilize the files that are there without modifying any configuration files. If the crud-module files are gone, it won't be looking for them.